# Can I exit and re-enter Russia with my visa-free privilege?

Tags: visas, russia, visa-free-entry

I'm a Brazilian citizen in Russia, with 90-day visa-free access every 180 days. I've only been here one week, but I need to leave the country for a family situation. Can I later return for the remainder of the 90 days, or am I simply barred from re-entry for another 90 days? Thank you!

Comment: The point of the *Schengen* 90/180 rule is to allow multiple short visits while still preventing people from living in the area without authorization. So the only restriction is on the total time spent in the area, not on how frequently one may enter.  I suppose the Russian rule is the same, but I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here is the [quote](https://%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%B4.%D1%80%D1%84/Deljatelnost/emvd/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81) from the website of The Russian Ministry of Internal Affairs:

> Срок временного пребывания в Российской Федерации иностранного гражданина, прибывшего в Российскую Федерацию в порядке, не требующем получения визы, не может превышать девяносто суток суммарно в течение каждого периода в сто восемьдесят суток...

Shortened free translation: no more than 90 days in any 180-day period; no limitation on the number of visits.